# Highstock, dynamically changing from percent stacking to normal stacking

Tags: highcharts

Like the title says, if you have a chart with percent stacking enabled for each series and then try to change to normal stacking using the series.update() method it does not work. It doesn't seem to do anything.

percent to normal example: http://jsfiddle.net/8tbPD/

The reverse does work though.

normal to percent example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tn3n9/

Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks.

```
    $('button').on('click', function() {

        for(var index in chart.series) {
            chart.series[index].update({stacking:'normal'});   
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried several changes, even to manually set some properties from 'percentage' to 'normal' and call `chart.redraw()`. No changes. If there is no any answer or hint, maybe you can ask at support.

Comment: I just came across this question, but the reverse seems working: http://jsfiddle.net/11o2z7cq/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you need to destroy and create a new chart.

Comment: Why can you go one way but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer on another forum: http://forum.highcharts.com/highstock-usage/dynamic-update-toggle-between-value-and-percentage-t31298/

Basically, add a series with "stacking" but with no data. Then show and hide that series (whose stacking-attribute will affect all other series) using JavaScript, e.g. button.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Historic and Estimated Worldwide Population Distribution by Region'
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['1750', '1800', '1850', '1900', '1950', '1999', '2050'],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
      title: {
        enabled: false
      }
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Percent'
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> ({point.y:,.0f} millions)<br/>',
      shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      area: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        lineColor: '#ffffff',
        lineWidth: 1,
        marker: {
          lineWidth: 1,
          lineColor: '#ffffff'
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Asia',
      data: [502, 635, 809, 947, 1402, 3634, 5268]
    }, {
      name: 'Africa',
      data: [106, 107, 111, 133, 221, 767, 1766]
    }, {
      name: 'Europe',
      data: [163, 203, 276, 408, 547, 729, 628]
    }, {
      name: 'America',
      data: [18, 31, 54, 156, 339, 818, 1201]
    }, {
      name: 'Oceania',
      data: [2, 2, 2, 6, 13, 30, 46]
    }, {
      showInLegend: false,
      stacking: 'percent'
    }]
  });

  // the button action
  var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
    $button = $('#button');
  $button.click(function() {
    var series = chart.series[5];
    if (series.visible) {
      series.hide();
      $button.html('Percent');
    } else {
      series.show();
      $button.html('Normal');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<button id="button">Normal</button>
```

Comment: Please don't leave insult in your post, when you can fix the problem directly. Use Stack Snippets, like what I edited.